# Remember text input without using PHP or Database

Tags: jquery, html, chat

I don't know if this is possible but...

I am attempting to create a **very** basic chat function that will anyone visiting that page to ask simple questions. I am restricted so I can only use HTML and JavaScript code so I'm very limited to how I can actually get this to work.

Is there any way to create a chat function that will allow multiple users to see a live conversation without the page to referesh because we can't save results to a database.

So far I have the code below which will get the chat to work however, no one else can see the conversation. Can we get the code to activly show the changes without the need to refresh the page so that others can see the conversation? Like using a live event or something.

If anyone has any suggestions I would much appreciate it.

**Code Example:**

```
<script>
    jQuery(document).ready(function(){
        $('button').click(function(){
            var message = $('textarea').val();
            var old = $('#chatbox').html();
            $('#chatbox').html(old + '<p>' + message + '</p>');
        });
    });
</script>

<h1>Chat</h1>
<div id="chatbox">
    <p>The chat box</p>
</div>
<div id="message">
<textarea class="textarea" name="comment" id="comment" placeholder="Ask a question..."></textarea>
<button>Post</button>
</div>
```

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/487AU.jpg)

Comment: Direct client to client communication using a web-browser is unlikely to be achievable with just HTML and JavaScript. You'd either need some sort of server-side script, or some other thing like a Java applet or Flash object.

Answer (score 0):

For the question *"we get the code to actively show the changes"* the answer is yes (in fact your current code should be doing that already), **but**, for the question *"so that others can see the conversation"* the answer is **no**.

Direct client-to-client communication is not possible with current browsers. JavaScript does allow using websockets, e.g., [socket.io](http://socket.io/), however the problem is there is no way to announce the IPs of other people currently viewing the same page, also, exposing the IPs of other people using your site raises privacy concerns.

If you are a bit more flexible in your ability to use something on the server-side then you can also look into using https://webrtc.org/ which is a standardized way of allowing client-to-client communication (but does need a server to mediate it).

Answer (score -1):

I once had this same problem where php could not be used locally.

1. How we solved it was by using AJAX to grab a php file outside of the website on a server somewhere else.
2. You could save the text into a text file using JavaScript then pull it in for all users.

This link could be helpful - https://thiscouldbebetter.wordpress.com/2012/12/18/loading-editing-and-saving-a-text-file-in-html5-using-javascrip/

Comment: This is why I gave the option 2 where I did not use any php

Comment: Your first option does use PHP, just because it's somewhere else doesn't mean it's not PHP.

Comment: I gave the first option because sometimes people try to run php locally on a phone for example and then it does not work so they think php can not work. whereas it can by putting the file outside the project and calling it via JavaScript. Why don't you focus on helping the person who asked the question instead of nitpicking others